# Update Record on basis of Second Highest Record of that data

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Sr  Na  Ra  Min    Max
1   cg  1   0.00    0.00
2   sg  1   0.00    0.00
3   cg  2   10.00   0.00
4   sg  2   10.00   0.00
5   cg  3   100.00  0.00
6   sg  3   100.00  0.00
7   cg  4   1000.00 0.00
8   sg  4   1000.00 0.00
```

Need Output Like

```
Sr  Na  Ra  Min     Max
1   cg  1   0.00    9.00
2   sg  1   0.00    9.00
3   cg  2   10.00   99.00
4   sg  2   10.00   99.00
5   cg  3   100.00  999.00
6   sg  3   100.00  999.00
7   cg  4   1000.00 0.00
8   sg  4   1000.00 0.00
```

Max cloumn need to update on basis of Ra Group Min Value Second Highest value -1 updated on MAX column.

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Please explain the output..

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to do an update self join of your table.  The join condition is that the current `Ra` value is one less than the `Ra` value from whose row we want to take the minimum value minus one.  This works nicely, as the final `Ra` value will not join to anything and so its max value would remain zero.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Ra, Min
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE t1
SET t1.Max = t2.Min - 1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Ra = t2.Ra - 1;
```

We could also use `LEAD` or `LAG` here but that would more strongly depend on the version of SQL Server you are using, which you never told us.